# IF(carts.price != product_segments.segment_price,1,0)AS price_change how to write this in laravel

Tags: laravel, if-statement, model

my query is

```
->where('customer_id', $user->id)->select('carts.*', 'product_segments.segment_price')->get();

if i add if condition like below it give an error 
->where('customer_id', $user->id)->select('carts.*', 'product_segments.segment_price', IF(carts.price != product_segments.segment_price,1,0)AS price_change)->get();
```

> ParseError: syntax error, unexpected 'IF' (T_IF), expecting ')' in
> file

how to write if condition in select statement of laravel query.

Answer (score 1):

Can use [selectRaw](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#selectraw) for statements with conditions or functions. Try with:

```
->where('customer_id', $user->id)
->selectRaw('carts.*, product_segments.segment_price, IF(carts.price != product_segments.segment_price, 1, 0) AS price_change')->get();
```

Search the page for `selectRaw` at the link to find other examples.